# How to use custom Java widgets in Qt Designer UI?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, qt-designer, qt-jambi, custom-widgets

I'm using Eclipse with the Qt Designer UI plugin for Qt Jambi.
Everything I'm writing is in Java. My problem is the following:

I've created a widget called `ParentWidget`, and another called `ChildWidget`. Now I would like to, in the Qt Designer (thus in the .jui files) use the `ChildWidget` in the `ParentWidget`. I can achieve this by circumventing the designer, and editing the generated Java files to use `ChildWidget` instead of `QWidget`... but I'd rather not edit generated files.

So the question is, how to insert a widget I've just created, using the Qt Designer?

Comment: There are examples in the Launchpad (ubuntu) and openSuSE Build Service (openSuSE/RHEL) of a current and functional Qt Designer that works with QtJambi.  Take a look at the *.xml files found in the plugin directories as I believe this to be related to using custom widgets.

Comment: @Darryl: Thanks, I'll have a look!